# Can't figure out this odd function

Tags: functions

The following function is said to be odd.
I'm supposed to find out the value of m; the answer to which is 3 and -1.
However, I cannot figure out a way to get this answer. Can anyone help me with this?

$f=\{(-3,a),(0,0),(a^2+2a,m)\}$

What I though was that since it is an odd function, $f(-x)=-f(x)$. Therefore, $f(-x)+f(x)=0$. Now if I get two pairs equal, I will have $(-3,a)=(a^2+2a,m)$. So, $a^2+2a=-3$ or $a^2+2a+3=0$. I'm stuck at this point. Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For an odd function you want the domain $\{-3,0,a^2+2a\}$ to be symmetric, i.e., you need $a^2+2a=+3$.